# Uninstall IntelliJ completely in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: intellij-idea

**How to completely uninstall intellij ultimate in ubuntu 20.04?
I followed every step from the official site, removed .config/Jetbrains, .local/share/Jetbrains, .cache/Jetbrains and deleted the untar folder of intellij. But when i again start intellij, it still fetches that i was logged in intelliJ.**

What to do?

Also, one more error is that when i again run .idea.sh with openjdk-8, it gives error that
**java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/intellij/util/lang/PathClassLoader has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0**

To overcome that, i have to switch to openjdk-17 and then run idea.sh.

Comment: Java registry is used for storing license details. Please check `~/.java/.userPrefs`

Comment: It is not recommended to use a custom JRE for running the IDE process as it may cause some technical problems. Try switching to JBR (JetBrains Runtime) as per https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under